# Why is a genome of an organism only given in the 5' -> 3' direction?

Tags: genetics

If u look up a genome of a certain organism or virus, it's always given in the 5' to 3' direction. I understand that one can derive the other direction very easily by just constructing the complementary strand.

Since genes can lie on both strands, why is only one strand given?

Comment: Think a little about how complementary strands bind to each-other with respect to 5' and 3' ends....

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. We use standard English here, rather than text abbreviations so please edit your question, replacing "u" by "you". This may seem pedantic, but it is all part and parcel of our aim to provide good clear questions that will attract answers of lasting use. All nucleic acid sequences are written in the 5' to 3' direction, to indicate the asymmetry of the phosphodiester bond, so are you asking for both strands to be presented, or the reverse complement of the genome sequence? And in what context? Cite a Genbank page and explain to us how you would like it different.